# Does Apache Ignite v2.7 support UPDATE queries with JOINS

Tags: join, sql-update, ignite, gridgain

I am trying to update a column with joins in GridGain but it is throwing an error.

The query I tried is:

```
UPDATE Person1 
inner JOIN  
cityDetails  
ON Person1.pincode = cityDetails.pincode
SET Person1.name= 'singh'
where Person1.country = 'US'
```

The error is:

> Syntax error in SQL statement " UPDATE PERSON1 INNER[*] JOIN CITYDETAILS ON PERSON1.PINCODE = CITYDETAILS.PINCODE SET PERSON1.NAME= 'singh' WHERE PERSON1.COUNTRY = 'US' "; expected "., AS, SET"; SQL statement: UPDATE Person1 inner JOIN cityDetails ON Person1.pincode = cityDetails.pincode SET Person1.name= 'singh' where Person1.country = 'US' [42001-197]

I have created index at pincode where I am joining the table.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

No apache ignite does not support joins on updates. You could use the `IN` Operator with a subquery in the `WHERE` part.

Comment: I tried this query :  update Person1 set Person1.name ='singh'
WHERE Person1.country IN (SELECT Person1.country FROM Person1 , cityDetails  WHERE Person1.pincode = cityDetails.pincode)                                                                         but its not giving any result .. however sub-query is working individually.